¿Como Reportar Respuestas que no son Respuestas correctamente?
En varias ocacione me encuentro con respuestas en el sitio con este contenido:

Claramente esto no es una respuesta, es un comentario ...

hay varias cosas que se puede hacer:

dejar un comentario diciendole al Usuario que no es una respuesta lo que acaba de agregar y que deberia eliminarla o editarla.

Entrar a la opcion de Reportar y llenar el formulario para que entre en la cola de revision de respuesta:



Formulario que me sale a mi por mi reputación:


El Problema:
Sucede que estos reportes por alguna razon son rechazado y suelen comentar que la herramienta no debe ser usada para este tipo de reporte ...

Aqui un ejemplo:


Como podran obervar la ultima fue rechazada... y si ven la respuesta es esta:


Pareciera que yo reporto algo por alguna razon del formulario y a la cola llega otra cosa ... y la respuesta del rechazo incluso es otra cosa sin contexto ...
en este punto quedo despistado ... ¿que hice mal?

A mí me ha pasado con "muy baja calidad". Entonces hay respuestas que por más que sean muy malas quedan ahí y la alternativa es votarlas negativamente

@Mateo  Sigo pensando que emitir votos negativos no es una solución... el voto negativo es para respuesta que si son una “respuesta” pero son “malas respuesta” ... eso no está relacionado a la “calidad” ... si no al contenido que puede producir “problemas a futuro” o sugerir malas “prácticas o agujeros de seguridad” ...

Cuando empece en este sitio, hice lo mismo que tú, y me las rechazaron con la misma explicación; una respuesta técnicamente errónea sigue siendo una respuesta. Después de un par de rechazos entendí el concepto. Ahora solo uso "reportar" cuando las "respuestas" son comentarios, spam o idioteces sin sentido. Cuando es "respuesta" y es mala, le dejo un comentario señalando el error/problema y en algunos casos le voto negativo, para advertir a los inocentes que pueden considerarla legítima.

A mí esto me causa un cortocircuito cerebral. Una respuesta de baja calidad puede ser una respuesta correcta pero corta y puede ser eliminada. En cambio, una respuesta incorrecta no es de baja calidad y no debe ser eliminada. Además, hay unas respuestas que ni se cómo clasificarlas.  Las que son correctas, del punto de vista de que todo lo que mencionan es correcto, pero no responden la pregunta (generalmente porque el que responde no entendió la pregunta)

Si no mal recuerdo, a mi me sucedió lo mismo en el pasado, voté un comentario que no respondía nada a modo de respuesta como "no es una respuesta", y mi voto fue rechazado. Cosa que me impactó bastante, por que repasé 3 veces el votar o no la respuesta. Esto necesita una delimitación certera entre cuando reconocer un comentario vs una respuesta. Por cierto, donde viste tus propios reportes @FranciscoIALover ?? para ver los mios
